# Should None be considered a data type? (Python)

Tags: python, theory

I know this sounds stupid, but I'm reading a programming book and they talk about how print() can return nothing (*None*). They use this code to explain it.

```
a = 10
b = 15

c = print('a =', a, 'b=', b)

print(c)
```

I get it, `c` isn't any data type that print() can take and, y'know, print it. `c` just has an empty value because it's not a valid data type.

But what data type is `c`? What data type is *None*? If `c` isn't a string, integer, float, nor a boolean, what is it? Shouldn't *None* be its own data type?

P.S. If I go to python and assign a variable *None* and print it, it recognises the data value and does not spit a name error. So theoretically, *None is its own data type, *right*?

Oh, and why does Python not convert `c` to string and then print it?

Comment: "Oh, and why does Python not convert c to string and then print it?" - it does, it prints `None`

Comment: Use `print(type(c))` to find out what `c` is.

Comment: Check out `Maybe`/`Option` in Haskell/Rust. Python's  `typing.Optional` gives us a similar type hint - `Optional[T]`. `Optional[int]` for example can have values int or None - it is shorthand for `Union[int, None]`. For the Option<T> type in Rust, None is one of two possible values for option: None, Some(T). None is not null, it's not 0 - it's the absent of Some. It's most like using an Enum value as sentinel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`None` is (like literally everything else in Python besides keywords) an **object**. Meaning it is an instance of a **class** (or *type* if you will). `None` is an instance of `NoneType`, which you can find out, if you do this:

```py
print(type(None))  # <class 'NoneType'>
```

So yes, `None` has its own data type in Python.

The class is special in the sense that it only ever has one instance: `None`. And yes, there is a string representation defined for the `NoneType` class. And the string representation is, well `"None"`, which you see, when you do this: (all equivalent in this case)

```py
print(None)
print(str(None))
print(repr(None))
```

**PS:**

It is also worth stressing that `None` is in fact a [singleton](/questions/tagged/singleton). Meaning there only ever is **exactly that one** instance of the `NoneType` class. This is why you can do **identity** comparisons with `None`, i.e.:

```py
if my_variable is None:
    ...
```

As opposed to **equality** comparisons (which of course work too) like this:

```py
if my_variable == None:
    ...
```

And when any function (including built-ins like `print`) have no explicit return statement or an empty one (like `return` without anything after it), they implicitly always return that one special `None` object.